# paste a symbol after paragraph in text php

Tags: php, regex

I have a text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste
>   mollitia similique, blanditiis quisquam suscipit optio quam culpa odit
>   ad magni sunt officiis, recusandae deleniti alias, natus commodi sed
>   expedita labore.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae
>   distinctio atque, eos quo. Autem commodi dicta, numquam natus illum
>   recusandae quos! Veniam nulla et temporibus necessitatibus vero
>   recusandae tempora saepe!

How I can with php paste a symbol `{{id}}` after every paragraph
? I need use `preg_replace`?

Comment: `(?=\n\s*\n|\z)` replace `{{id}}`

Comment: The idea with SO is you try it, and if it does not work ... Then you ask a question and post the code you have tried

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/tcHX1z/1)

```
(?=\n\s*\n|\z)
```

- `(?=\n\s*\n|\z)` Positive lookahead ensuring one of the following options matches

  - `\n\s*\n` Matches line-feed, any number of whitespace characters, and another line-feed. The reason `\n{2}` or `\n\n` isn't used is because *sometimes* people accidentally add other whitespace characters like spaces and so the regex doesn't catch those locations since it's not two `\n` back-to-back.
  - `\z` Assert position at the end of the string. This matches the end of the last paragraph.

Substitution: `{{id}}`

---

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##nVLLakJBDN3fr0hBUMtFP8CKdFnoppuuhBJnogbm5SRTSq3fbnOvFFx3NSQ5OY@ZKcdyvT5tyrF03aQSrGG6nG3W27SVx2362X7Pl9NVNxGtw@g1V4rARVoEn0OuIKyAkbQHl5OQU9JWAT0XFnacDkCBdQEvogQxBysYbSty4FOjHnYBk7cmC5way6lhBGnijEAhF@UMY8@1UBCyH/Q8RDwkNlwyzH5vQiw9VHJNjA0JPAVKxgoYGG2UUJuYxRiNAYQ80FchI0MIuLNUi677f7i3NkiyKCc3GEYdo1EeMuUFPDc15j91z07RLLU4BrtZ4xBM9i6BLcoDvFuKAdNCQCAF4ym58s42EjkSc4g6lp9U8/3@DWlXjVToYXzDthMdXvF8Zn@5WKsjd8xQKh0@KpWAjmb2B3q4QYdT63zVXa@/)

```
<?php

$re = '/(?=\n\s*\n|\z)/';
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste mollitia similique, blanditiis quisquam suscipit optio quam culpa odit ad magni sunt officiis, recusandae deleniti alias, natus commodi sed expedita labore.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae distinctio atque, eos quo. Autem commodi dicta, numquam natus illum recusandae quos! Veniam nulla et temporibus necessitatibus vero recusandae tempora saepe!';
$subst = '{{id}}';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

---

Result:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste
>   mollitia similique, blanditiis quisquam suscipit optio quam culpa odit
>   ad magni sunt officiis, recusandae deleniti alias, natus commodi sed
>   expedita labore.{{id}}
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae
>   distinctio atque, eos quo. Autem commodi dicta, numquam natus illum
>   recusandae quos! Veniam nulla et temporibus necessitatibus vero
>   recusandae tempora saepe!{{id}}

Comment: But in php how this be? `preg_replace('(?=\n\s*\n|\z)', $text)` ?

Comment: @Tatata see my edit. I included code.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry, but if I have text with `<p>` without spaces? But paragraphs with html

Comment: @Tatata in that case you should use a parser. See [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
str_replace("\r\n\r\n", "{{id}}\r\n\r\n", $variableWithTheText)
```

This assumes that your paragraphs are seperated by two `\r\n`'s

Comment: What if `\r` isn't used? Also doesn't work on last paragraph

Comment: just use `\n` instead of `\r\n`